# alerts con condicionales de tipo checkbox

Tags: javascript, entrada

tengo un problema y es que estoy tratando de hacer una lista de inputs de tipo checkbox, que cuando se presionen algunos y su valor sea true, este lance una alerta, y que cuando se presione el resto lance otra, pero sin tener que recargar la pagina

```js
var dedo1 = document.getElementById("dedo1");
var dedo2 = document.getElementById("dedo2");
var dedo3 = document.getElementById("dedo3");
var dedo4 = document.getElementById("dedo4");
var dedo5 = document.getElementById("dedo5");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");



function web(){
 
 if (dedo1.checked == false && dedo2.checked == false && (dedo3.checked == true && dedo4.checked == true) && dedo5.checked == false) {
  alert("ignicion");
  location.reload(true);
 }

 else if (dedo1.checked == true && dedo2.checked == true && (dedo3.checked == true && dedo4.checked == true) && dedo5.checked == true) {
  alert("se corto el flujo");
  location.reload(true);
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spidey.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="caja">
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo1" class="de dedo1">
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo2" class="de dedo2">
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo3" class="de dedo3">
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo4" class="de dedo4">
 <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo5" class="de dedo5">
 <br>
 <input type="button" name="" id="btn" class="btn">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="spidey.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que recargues la página para tener todos los inputs de nuevo en el estado inicial (checked), basta con hacer un pequeño método que se encargue de resetear el valor de los inputs que sean de tipo checkbox una vez se lance la alerta como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function web() {
    var dedo1 = document.getElementById("dedo1");
    var dedo2 = document.getElementById("dedo2");
    var dedo3 = document.getElementById("dedo3");
    var dedo4 = document.getElementById("dedo4");
    var dedo5 = document.getElementById("dedo5");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    if (dedo1.checked == false && dedo2.checked == false && (dedo3.checked == true && dedo4.checked == true) && dedo5.checked == false) {
        alert("ignicion");
    }

    else if (dedo1.checked == true && dedo2.checked == true && (dedo3.checked == true && dedo4.checked == true) && dedo5.checked == true) {
        alert("se corto el flujo");
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    web();
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && event.target.type == 'checkbox') {
            web();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo1" class="de dedo1">
        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo2" class="de dedo2">
        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo3" class="de dedo3">
        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo4" class="de dedo4">
        <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="" id="dedo5" class="de dedo5">
        <br>
        <input type="button" name="" id="btn" class="btn" onclick="web()">
</div>
```

Comment: hola, gracias por la  ayuda, la idea no es de regresar todos los valores a default, si no que hacer que a pagina pueda cambiar acorde a los inputs que estan en true, sin necesidad de crear un botón para que verifique el valor de ellos y que sea algo que pueda verificar el valor de ellos y lanzar un alert en el momento que una condición se cumpla

Comment: Ok, he ajustado el código de la respuesta para atender a la necesidad que tienes, lo puedes hacer a través de un listener de JavaScript, puedes escuchar clicks sobre el document o por cada input, de acuerdo a lo que necesites.